# How to modify the \caption command of the subcaption package

Tags: captions, subcaption

This is an add-on to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638247/whats-the-proper-way-to-renew-caption-command-for-short-and-long-description).

Same usecase: "make `\caption` to print both short and long captions for a float, where short caption uses boldface"

Solution by Teepeemm was

```
\let\oldcaption=\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{\oldcaption[#1]{\textbf{#1} #2}}
```

and it works perfectly.

But I also use the `subcaption` package and it breaks it for some reason. Any fixes?

MWE (or minimum not working example):

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{\oldcaption[#1]{\textbf{#1} #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{5cm}{1cm}
    \caption[This is a figure]{This is the more detailed description of the figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \rule{5cm}{1cm}
    \caption[This is a table]{This is the more detailed description of the table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Edit: Added the complete solution from the previous question

Comment: Can't you simply use: `\caption[\bfseries This is a table]{This is the more detailed description of the table}`?  Then you do not need to redefine the `\caption` command.

Comment: It makes a difference where `\let\oldcaption=\caption` is placed.  You could use `\makeatletter \let\oldcaption=\caption@caption \makeatother` to make sure you are using the caption package caption.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That doesn't seem to work. Just tried it in several variations. Also, shouldn't it work anyways, if `\let\oldcaption=\caption` is placed after `\usepackage{subcpation}` as `\caption` has already be redefined at that point?

Comment: Unless you are using something like KOMA, which redefines \caption at the beginning of each figure or table.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well, I do use KOMA (scrreprt), but if I comment out `\usepackage{subcaption}` it still works, so it must have something to do with `subcaption` (or `caption` as my tests suggest which is included in `subcaption`)

Comment: The simple answer is that KOMA is not compativle with subcaption.  However, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/can-the-package-caption-be-used-with-komascript-classes/383025?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C32.3076#383025 (which was presumably down voted by a KOMA purist, even though it works).